# Template Haskell: reify in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, template-haskell

Is it somehow possible to do [reify](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/template-haskell/2.8.0.0/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH.html#v%3areify) in GHCi?

When I try it using 'runQ' it complains "can not do reify in the IO monad".

```
>>> runQ (reify ''Bool)
Template Haskell error: Can't do `reify' in the IO monad
*** Exception: user error (Template Haskell failure)
```

I'm not looking for `:t` or something, only for a way to quickly check what `reify` returns without writing it to a file and loading that file into GHCi.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You just have to run it from a splice instead of using `runQ`:

```
> $(stringE . show =<< reify ''Bool)
"TyConI (DataD [] GHC.Types.Bool [] [NormalC GHC.Types.False [],NormalC GHC.Types.True []] [])"
```

Comment: You can use `putStrLn $(stringE . pprint =<< reify ''Bool)` to get pretty-printed output.

Comment: Is it possible to actually extract the value into a variable, instead of just converting it to a string?